# A number turn into a vector in R and the answer turn out to be the sum of components of the vector

Tags: r

```
UrnA =rep(c(10,5,1),c(5,5,5))
UrnB =rep(c(20,5,1),c(9,3,3))
n=1e3
sum=0
for( i in 1:n ){
  dice=sample(1:6,1)
  sum=sum+(dice<=4)*sample(UrnA,2,replace = FALSE)+(dice>=5)*sample(UrnB,2,replace = FALSE)
}
E=sum/n
```

I want to use the sentences above to solve the problem below.
"Urn A contains 5 $10 bills, 5 $5 bills, and 5 $1 bills.
    Urn B contains 9 $20 bills, 3 $5 bills, and 3 $1 bills.
A dice is thrown.  If it lands on 1,2,3, or 4, two bills are drawn from Urn A (without replacement), 
Otherwise two bills are drawn from Urn B.   Let X = the total value of the bills drawn. 
(a) Use simulations to estimate E[X]."
And the problem is that,when I run the sentence the sum turn out to be a array with two components which really makes me confused.And I calculate it myself and the sum of each components of sum turn out to be the right answer . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB5wE.png)

Comment: This is because when you draw two samples from Urn A or B, it gives you an array of two numbers, which is then used to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `for` loop if you consider that rolling a single die `n` times is the same as rolling `n` dice once.

```
UrnA <- rep(c(10,5,1), c(5,5,5))
UrnB <- rep(c(20,5,1), c(9,3,3))
n <- 1e3

set.seed(2018);
sum(as.integer(sapply(sample(1:6, n, replace = T), function(x)
    if (x <= 4) sample(UrnA, 2) else sample(UrnB, 2))))
#[1] 15818
```

I'm using a fixed seed here for reproducibility; remove if necessary.

---

We can confirm convergence by repeating the process 1000 times

```
val <- sapply(1:1000, function(x)
    sum(as.integer(sapply(sample(1:6, n, replace = T), function(x)
        if (x <= 4) sample(UrnA, 2) else sample(UrnB, 2)))))
ggplot(data.frame(idx = 1:1000, val = val), aes(idx, val)) +
    geom_point() +
    ylim(0, pretty(max(val))[2])
```

[image]

Comment: This is not correct, try running the code now and again, it does not coverge.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `sample` function will return a set of two values. You need to sum their components.

```
# Instead of
sum=sum+(dice<=4)*sample(UrnA,2,replace = FALSE)+(dice>=5)*sample(UrnB,2,replace = FALSE)
#Use:
sum=sum+sum((dice<=4)*sample(UrnA,2,replace = FALSE)+(dice>=5)*sample(UrnB,2,replace = FALSE))
```

Comment: This is correct. Can you write the full code for OP. also try to avoid using `sum` as a variable since it is a function in base R